# Find the longest increasing subarray

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, list

For example : input = [1,2,3,1,5,7,8,9]  , output = [1,5,7,8,9]

find out the longest continuous increasing subarray

I have tried on my own like this :

```
def longsub(l):
    newl = []
    for i in range(len(l)) :
        if l[i] < l[i+1] :
            newl.append(l[i])
        else :
            newl = []
    return newl
```

But it would get error since the list index out of range. (It could not get the value after last value)

```
def longsub(l):
    newl = []
    for i in range(len(l)) :
        if l[i] > l[i-1] :
            newl.append(l[i])
        else :
            newl = []
    return newl
```

And then I did this, but I would get the result without the first value of increasing subarray.

What should I rectify my code? Thanks!

Comment: Here is a hint. Try writing a function that returns the index and length of the longest increasing subarray. Then use that information to get the subarray afterwards.

Comment: enumerate can return the index but how should I use it within?

Answer (score 0):

Suppose that you had this helper at your disposal:

```
def increasing_length_at(l, i):
    """Returns number of increasing values found at index i.

    >>> increasing_length_at([7, 6], 0)
    1
    >>> increasing_length_at([3, 7, 6], 0)
    2
    """
    val = l[i] - 1
    for j in range(i, len(l)):
        if l[j] <= val:  # if non-increasing
            break
        val = l[j]
    return j - i
```

How could you use that as part of a solution?

Comment: OP is learning. I am trying to offer a scaffold, the first step or two on a ladder, so they can go the rest of the way. Complex problem solving is always about breaking an "impossible" problem into smaller ones that you know the answer to.

Answer (score 0):

You could use 2 `loops` (first to iterate over the input and the second loop to  iterate from the index of the first loop until the end):

```
inp = [1,2,3,1,5,7,8,9]
output = [1,5,7,8,9]

i, res = 0, []

while i < len(inp):
    tempResult = [startNum := inp[i]] # Python>3.8: Walrus operator
    for j in range(i+1, len(inp)):
        if startNum > inp[j]:
            i = j-1 # skip already compared items!
            break
        tempResult.append(startNum := inp[j]) # Python>3.8: Walrus operator
    if len(tempResult) > len(res):
        res = tempResult
    i += 1

print(res, res == output)
```

Out:

```
[1, 5, 7, 8, 9] True
```

Comment: I don't understand the `if tempResult` guard, given that it is _always_ a truthy list from the moment it's initialized.

Comment: I like the `for j` loop. The `for i` loop leads to O(N^2) quadratic behavior, which gets ugly if we assign `l = list(range(100_000))`. Consider how you might exploit an increasing_length_at() helper to leapfrog over a big stretch of monotonic values in search of the next such stretch.

Answer (score -2):

Firstly, you can use `len(l) - 1` to avoid the `IndexError`. However, your approach is invalid since this would just return the last increasing sub. Here's my approach:

```
def longsub(l):
    res, newl = [], []
    for i in range(len(l)-1):
        if l[i] < l[i+1]:
            newl.append(l[i])
        else:
            newl.append(l[i])
            res.append(newl)
            newl = []
    if newl: res.append(newl)
    return max(res, key=len)
input = [1,2,3,4,5,1,5,7,8,9]
print(longsub(input))
```

Output:

```
>>> [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```